# C# get Enumerable<string> in all orders

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get all combination of strigns? Let say I have in List "a", "b", "c" and I want get "abc", "bac", "cab", "bca", "bac", "cba", "acb". I need this for long enurable as 3 so I can not do this hardcode. What is the best way?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/